# Finding the Last Known Location, in android emulator

Tags: android, location, android-virtual-device, locationlistener

I am trying to get the last known location of the user , I am using getLastKnownLocation method because I only want to read the location once, I am testing the app in emulator not a real handset, but the location is null, my code

```
locMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location myLoc = locMgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); 
if(myLoc != null)
{}
else 
{
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "coudn't get your location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

the problem is that I don't know when to send the location(from DDMS) to the emulator(I tried to send it before and after opening the app sometimes it works)

I can get the location by imlemting LocationListener and do:

```
mLocMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE); 
mLocMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 3, this);
```

and overide the onLocationChanged() method that works fine but it will tell me each time the location change and I only need to read the location once.
so how to get the current location of the user once?

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a service or a thread that can callback when once the location is determined? That way you can keep on checking every so often.

Comment: no I simply want to get the location once, what is wrong with this method? can't it be done with getLastKnownLocation() method

Comment: Obviously it does not work as expected but it sounds like after some unknown amount of time you do get a valid response back. Whatever the reason for this delay is, a thread would let your application wait for the response while still moving forward with creating the display for the user and allowing for interactions.

Comment: the problem is that using requestLocationUpdates(), it works fine with no delay, 
I am testing(getLastKownLocation()) in an emulator so I send the location, and so there should not be any delay, in fact it is not a delay simply it does not work(return null)

Comment: Ahh well there ya go. The emulator is rubbish for most hardware interactions.